# Will a 0.400mm thick PCB be too flexible?

Tags: pcb, core, flexible, manufacturing-process

My PCB will roughly have the following stackup:

35um copper foil (tracks)
100um FR4 prepreg
200um FR4 core
100um FR4 prepreg
35um copper foil (tracks)

This gives a total board thickness of around .400mm
Since I've only ever seen 1.6mm boards, I wonder how a .400mm will be. Too flexible? Will the core keep the board relatively rigid, or will I be able to bend it like a ribbon cable? Will there be problems with drilling, assembly? Can I still have a BGA soldered
onto it?

Edit: board dimensions are 80x50mm

Comment: Not like a ribbon but still it will be pretty flexible. Now that's a relative term and it's difficult to convey properly. But I'd suggest getting a 0.4mm pcb from somewhere and see it for yourself. Also, it depends on PCB size so try getting something similar to what your original design is.

Comment: BGAs are prone to solder contact issues (fatigue, cracks) due to bending and warpage in PCBs so I would certainly not put it on a 0.4mm pcb.
Normal smd IC's have legs that can bend a little bit relieving the stress on the solder joint when bent.

Comment: The smallest PCB I've worked with was 0.032" which is about 0.8mm.... that gets flimsy enough that a panel begins to sag holding it from the edges. I can only imagine that a 0.4mm would need special considerations for handling and mounting.

Comment: Even getting it bound up when putting the screws in may put an undesirable warp in it. Of course, you didn't say how big it is, which is a huge factor there.

Comment: Added board dimensions.

Comment: Why not make it 1.6mm and all of your problems go away?

Comment: It'll be flexible. But we don't know the application and it's constraints so nobody can tell if it's too flexible. Got a vibration specification? what's the mass of the heaviest component? If you need that stackup for controlled impedance or something, but you can afford the weight and space for a 1.6mm pcb you can embed that stackup in a 4 layer pcb and not use the other layers.

Comment: You're going to want to check with your manufacturer to make sure they have core and prepreg thicknesses that meet your requirements, and that they are physically able to manufacture a board with the stackup you suggest.

Comment: _"35um copper foil (tracks), 100um FR4 prepreg, 200um FR4 core, 100um FR4 prepreg, 35um copper foil (tracks). This gives a total board thickness of around .400mm"_ - Sounds to me more like a total of .470mm, almost 20% more than what you quoted ;)

Comment: Steve, @Brian: The prepreg thicknesses need to be this size to get the right impedance (the core contains GND and PWR plane). I would like to have the core thickness below 10 mils, to reduce the mounting inductance of my bypass capacitors (otherwise i'll need more). I would like to avoid >4 layers, since it otherwise gets to expensive (prototype/low volume). Brian, can you elaborate on the embedding?

Comment: What frequencies are you working with that you expect via inductance to be critical to performance?

Comment: I have to say, unless its very critical to have such a thin board, I'd avoid it. I've made .032in boards that I was uncomfortable with how thin and "flexible", or flimsy I should say, they are. Additionally, can board houses actually be able to make that thin of a board?

Comment: @Rayray, the board house won't care. They have to make 0.004" boards to be able to laminate up 16-layer 0.064" boards.

Comment: @ThePhoton: The bypass capacitors are for decoupling of DDR3 power supply and works also as stitching caps for signals changing reference planes (PWR plane is my second ref. plane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a 1 mm thick board with dimensions about 3 x 15 cm. This design was noticeably more flexible than a similar 1.6 mm board, and flexible enough that I worried about the possibility of board flex causing damage to mounted components or the solder joints holding them to the board.

Given that the flexibility of a board depends on the cube of the board thickness (because it depends on the [area moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area) of the cross-section of the board), and your proposed stackup is less than half the thickness of mine, I expect you will need to take special care to mount this board at multiple points, or provide some other stiffening mechanism, to avoid damaging the board or the parts on it.